# ASP.NET: Hide All Div Contents - Failed to load viewstate. error

Tags: asp.net, html, hide, visible

I am trying to hide the whole div programmatically, using the following code:

```
System.Web.UI.Control divMask = (System.Web.UI.Control)this.Page.FindControl("urinaDiv");

System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl htmlCtrl = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)divMask;            
                            htmlCtrl.Attributes["Visible"] = "false";
```

And here is the div:

```
 <div id="urinaDiv" sytle="width: 600px" runat="server">
                                <asp:Label ID="relatorioUrinaLabel" runat="server" Text="Relatórios Urina"></asp:Label>


                                <br />
                                <br />



                                    <asp:GridView ID="urinasGridview" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource3">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="idUtente" HeaderText="IDUten" SortExpression="idUtente" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="nome" HeaderText="Nome" SortExpression="nome" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="apelido" HeaderText="Apelido" SortExpression="apelido" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="data" HeaderText="Data" SortExpression="data" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="idUtenteMarcacao" HeaderText="idUtenteMarcacao" SortExpression="idUtenteMarcacao" visible="false"/>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="densidade" HeaderText="Densidade" SortExpression="densidade" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ph" HeaderText="pH" SortExpression="ph" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="glicose" HeaderText="Glicose" SortExpression="glicose" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="proteinas" HeaderText="Proteínas" SortExpression="proteinas" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="limitacoes" HeaderText="Limitcações" SortExpression="limitacoes" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="observacoes" HeaderText="Obs." SortExpression="observacoes" />
                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>



                                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource3" runat="server" SelectMethod="getRelatoriosUrina" 
                                    TypeName="BusinessLogicLayer.Lab_Manager" ></asp:ObjectDataSource>

                                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource6" runat="server" SelectMethod="getRelatoriosUrinaUtente" 
                                    TypeName="BusinessLogicLayer.Lab_Manager" OnSelecting="urinaSelecting"   ><SelectParameters>
                                              <asp:Parameter Name="idUtente" /></SelectParameters></asp:ObjectDataSource>
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                     </div>
```

But I get the following error:

Failed to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate during the previous request.  For example, when adding controls dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type and position of the controls added during the initial request.

Thanks alot in advance!!

Comment: Anyone? I guess this is trivial :s

Comment: why don't you just use `urinaDiv.Visible=false` ?

Comment: Weird, before I made this question, yesterday, I tryed that because it was the obvious solution to try and Visual Studio 2012 was giving me a warning about the div being not recognized... But today I tryed and it works! Thanks alot mate :D    ___  Post it as an answer I will be glad to accept it ! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to do all that casting when you have `runat="server"`

Use just Visible property:

`urinaDiv.Visible=false;`